# Как получить уникальные доменные имена из базы? И возможно ли?

Tags: sql

Есть база емаилов, допустим таблица emails, где есть одна колонка: value, и значение разные.. например test@mail.ru или test@gmail.com.. емаилов очень много, меня интересует такой вопрос, можно ли вывести все данные с уникальным значением после @ , чтобы понимать какие почтовые сервисы присутствуют в таблице,
то есть допустим миллион записей и я на выходе был получил от каждого почтового сервиса по записи, это возможно?

Comment: На сколько знаю, стандартом SQL пара подходящих функций описана, но не обязательны к реализации. Поэтому для абстрактного SQL нет решения, а вот для конкретных реализаций - скорей всего найдётся. Уточните какой диалект интересует

Comment: разумеется. Вам в любом случае понадобиться distinct для получения уникальных строк. И какие либо строковые функции, для выделения нужной части из емейла. Только в каждой СУБД свой набор функций. Например в MySQL можно воспользоваться substring_index(), в oracle выделением на основе регулярного выражения, в postgesql что то вроде split_part и т.п.

Comment: какая у вас СУБД?